# Rails 3.1 invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)

Tags: utf-8, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9

I'm trying to pass this simple assertion

`assert_select '.price', /\€[,\d]+\.\d\d/`

In the view the code for the .price class is

```
<span class="price">
 <%= number_to_currency(product.price, options = {:format => "%u%n", :unit => "&euro;"}) %> </span>
```

When I'm using the default `<%= number_to_currency(product.price) %>` everything's just fine. When I switch to the Euro it just wont work.

This is the error message:

```
/Users/noapologize/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `require': /Users/noapologize/rails_projects/depot/test/functional/store_controller_test.rb:11: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8) (SyntaxError)
/Users/noapologize/rails_projects/depot/test/functional/store_controller_test.rb:11: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
/Users/noapologize/rails_projects/depot/test/functional/store_controller_test.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
    assert_select '.price', /\€[,\d]+\.\d\d/
```

I suppose the way I'm writing this assert_select is wrong. Could someone enlighten me?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the escape slash from the Euro sign this regexp will compile properly and work.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. It's weird because that how the Pragmatic Book has it. I don't get it. Why it works for the $ but not for the €? Is it the byte length of the character or something? Again, thank you for your answer and your time.

Comment: It's because the dollar is a used as a command character in regexps, so you need to escape it. If the Pragprog book says you need to escape the euro you  can file a bug against their book ;-)